# Mounting an antenna base on a roof using only double sided tape?

Tags: metals

I want to put a vertical antenna on top of my roof. The antenna is basically 4 meters of PVC pipe and 5 meters of 19mm aluminium tubing.

The roof at my house is corrugated sheet metal, and I want to avoid drilling (and even touching the current screws as much as possible).

Here's a render of my idea:

[image]

The mast itself will be, of course, held by ropes. Will double sided tape (3M VHB) be able to prevent the base from sliding around during installation? Will the tape hold up to thermal expansion of the corrugated sheet?

The main idea of this support is being able to pivot the antenna in case of very strong winds, or servicing it (it has a coil in the middle).

Answer (score 1):

This is really hard to tell. But from experience, it probably wont hold. First, double sided tape is nowhere strong enough to hold a shaft that long securely - at least in the long run. The glue used on tapes wears off depending on exposure to heat, humidity, constant movement and UV - on a roof probably all of that is present.
So In your place, I'd think about other concepts. If you don't want to touch the roof as little as possible, consider putting the antenna onto a remote foundation next to your house for example.
But it's really hard to tell without knowing more and the people here probaby won't be able to help this way. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

3M's outdoor tape is rather strong. I have attached a number of sports badges to a motor vehicle, which was then subjected to about five years of periodic car washes and Florida hot summers and "cold" winters.

The surface was thoroughly cleaned before application, as should be the case for your project. One can expect the tape to hold in the manner you suggest, although the thermal variations may weaken it a bit, eventually causing it to fail. Consider as an alternative method to provide additional reinforcement.

Clean and apply tape to the surfaces involved, but also provide for a retention system surrounding the base. For example, using rectangular blocks (steel is best to match thermal characteristics) placed around the perimeter of the base, spaced a bit free of the base, would allow for thermal expansion and contraction, while providing security that the base won't go out-of-column from the down-guys.

[image: mast base image]

You could undercut the blocks in such a way as to create additional retention, but that may be overkill.

It's important to consider to periodically inspect the mount, perhaps six months apart to ensure that it remains in place.